# How do I filter a dictionary based on the partial string matches?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, dictionary, lookup

I have a dictionary of values:

```
dic = {1: "a1+b+c", 2: "a1+c+v", 3: "a1+z+e", 4: "a2+p+a", 5: "a2+z+v", 6: "a3+q+v", ...}
```

I have a page in Flask, that has checkboxes for each partial string value in a dictionary, e.g. checkboxes "a", "b", "c",... etc. On the page, the checkboxes are located in groups a1, a2, a3, etc.

I need to filter the dictionary by the partial values based on the values of the selected checkboxes, for example, when selecting "c" in group a1, it would return:

```
 1: a1+b+c
 2: a1+c+v
```

When selecting "z" from group a2, it would return:

```
 5: "a2+z+v"
```

The code that generates an error is:

```
sol = [k for k in dic if 'a1' in k]
```

Can someone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily solve this with a quite short function:

```
def lookup(dct, *args):
    for needle in args:
        dct = {key: value for key, value in dct.items() if needle in value}
    return dct
```

For example:

```
>>> dic = {1: "a1+b+c", 2: "a1+c+v", 3: "a1+z+e", 4: "a2+p+a", 5: "a2+z+v", 6: "a3+q+v"}
>>> lookup(dic, "a1", "c")
{1: 'a1+b+c', 2: 'a1+c+v'}
```

---

However that always needs to iterate over all keys for each "needle". You can do better if you have a helper dictionary (I'll use a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) here) that stores all keys that match one needle (assuming `+` is supposed to be a delimiter in your dictionary):

```
from collections import defaultdict

helperdict = defaultdict(set)
for key, value in dic.items():
    for needle in value.split('+'):
        helperdict[needle].add(key)
```

That `helperdict` now contains all keys that match one particular part of a value:

```
>>> print(dict(helperdict))
{'z': {3, 5}, 'p': {4}, 'a1': {1, 2, 3}, 'a3': {6}, 'v': {2, 5, 6}, 'a2': {4, 5}, 'e': {3}, 'b': {1}, 'a': {4}, 'c': {1, 2}, 'q': {6}}
```

And using [`set.intersection`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection) allows you to quickly get all matches for different combinations:

```
>>> search = ['a2', 'z']
>>> matches = set.intersection(*[helperdict[needle] for needle in search])
>>> {match: dic[match] for match in matches}
{5: 'a2+z+v'}
```

It's definitely longer than the first approach and requires more external memory but if you plan to do several queries it will be much faster.